# Java reading text file in eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, spring

I am trying to read a text file available in a different package but in same project but always getting InputStream as null.

```
public class ReadFileApp {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Thread currentThread = Thread.currentThread();
        ClassLoader classLoader = currentThread.getContextClassLoader();
        InputStream inputStream = classLoader.getResourceAsStream("/com/rpsoft/response/fileOneResponse.txt");

        String response = null;
        try {
            response = new String(FileCopyUtils.copyToByteArray(inputStream));
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        System.out.println("Current Thread : " + currentThread);
        System.out.println("Class Loader : " + classLoader);
        System.out.println("InputStream : "+ inputStream);
        System.out.println("Response : " + response);
    }
}
```

### Getting Exception :

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No InputStream specified
    at org.springframework.util.Assert.notNull(Assert.java:112)
    at org.springframework.util.FileCopyUtils.copy(FileCopyUtils.java:106)
    at org.springframework.util.FileCopyUtils.copyToByteArray(FileCopyUtils.java:156)
    at com.rpsoft.filetransport.ReadFileApp.main(ReadFileApp.java:18)
```

Comment: Seems that your file doesn't exist.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try removing the leading slash from the resouce name.

```
classLoader.getResourceAsStream("com/rpsoft/response/fileOneResponse.txt");
```

instead of

```
classLoader.getResourceAsStream("/com/rpsoft/response/fileOneResponse.txt");
```

Comment: Thanks it's solved exactly as you have mentioned above.

Answer (score 1):

You can try any one based on the file location in the project.

```
// Read from same package 
getClass().getResourceAsStream("fileOneResponse.txt")

// Read from resources folder parallel to src in your project
new File("resources/fileOneResponse.txt")

// Read from src/resources folder
getClass().getResource("/resources/fileOneResponse.txt")

// Read from src/resources folder
getClass().getResourceAsStream("/resources/fileOneResponse.txt")
```